# SabreDAV и WebDAV в Windows

Tags: php, windows, webdav

Пробую «завести» SabreDAV на Apache. Для авторизации использую следующий `BasicCallback`:

```
$authBackend = new DAV\Auth\Backend\BasicCallBack(function($userName, $password) {
    if ($userName == 'admin' && $password == 'admin') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

При авторизации в браузере всё красиво, ввожу admin/admin - показываются файлы и папки.

Но при монтировании раздела в Windows 7, через мастер, или через `net use` всё время получаю ошибку

> The network name cannot be found

Если убрать авторизацию - папка монтируется корректно, всё работает. Для Windows пробовал ставить заплатку от Майкрософта, в реестре для `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters` стоит 2, но проблему с авторизацией это не решает.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score -1):

Помимо правки реестра (да, выставляем 2) должна быть включена служба Веб-клиент (выполняется\автоматически).